# Full Clustering in Apache Traffic Server

Tags: proxy, load-balancing, reverse-proxy, apache-traffic-server

I followed the steps mentioned in the [official documentation](https://trafficserver.readthedocs.org/en/latest/admin/cluster-howto.en.html#full-clustering) for full clustering of multiple ATS instances. I installed 2 instances of ATS on 2 different Ubuntu machines (having the same specs, OS versions and hardware), and both of these act as a reverse proxy for web service hosted on a Tomcat server in a different machine. I wasnt able to set up the cluster. Here are some of the queries that I have.

- **They are on the same switch or same VLAN** : The two Ubuntu machines on which I installed the ATS are connected to the same switch. They have the same interface mentioned in the `/etc/network/interfaces`. Are these enough or there is something else that has to be done to get the clustering?.
- Running the comment **traffic_line -r proxy.process.cluster.nodes** : This returned `1` after I ran the `traffic_line -x` and `traffic_line -L` commands. But, in the cluster.config file, there isnt any additions or changes.

Moreover, when I make a query to one of these ATS instances (I have mapped the URLs in the `remap.config` file), both of them cache the responses locally and is not shared across.

From this information, can anyone tell me if I am doing something wrong. Let me know if anymore info is required.

Comment: Is this a programming question? Try [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/about).

Answer (score 1):

Are these on virtual machines? I almost wasted 2 days trying to figure out what is wrong, when I initially set it up on openvz containers. Out of a wild guess, I decided to migrate to 2 physical nodes, and it went well. See [Apache Traffic Server Clustering not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21535091/apache-traffic-server-clustering-not-working)

```
proxy.process.cluster.nodes returns 1
```

means that it is just the standalone single node, and the second node on the cluster is not discovered.

Answer (score 1):

Try a tcp dump for multicast and broadcast messages. If the other server's IP is not showing in the discovery packet, it has something to do at the network level, where the netops might have disabled multicast packet forwarding across switches.