# Apache Traffic Server Clustering not working

Tags: caching, distributed-caching, distributed-cache, apache-traffic-server

I compiled trafficserver-4.1.2 on two openvz containers running on Debian Squeeze, located on two different physical root nodes. Everything including caching is working fine, except for the clustering. I added the same name to the two nodes, as

```
traffic_line -s proxy.config.proxy_name -v fetest
```

Configured to run on port 80

```
traffic_line -s proxy.config.http.server_ports -v 80
```

Followed the doc on http://trafficserver.readthedocs.org/en/4.0.x/admin/cluster-howto.en.html

```
traffic_line -r proxy.local.cluster.type
1
```

and

```
traffic_line -r proxy.config.cluster.ethernet_interface
venet0:0
```

But

```
traffic_line -r proxy.process.cluster.nodes
1
```

The second node is not showing up. Only a single node is being showed. Whether the other node is up or not, this is all it shows up, and there are no entries added up in cluster.config.

Comment: Is this a programming question? Try [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/about).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks more like a multicasting issue. Make sure your root nodes/mother ships are on the same switch/vlan. A tcp dump on the interfaces can show you whether the cluster is able to communicate each other using multicast.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a compatibility issue with openVZ containers network interface. I switched this to physical nodes, and this started to identify and share information.

```
# traffic_line -r proxy.process.cluster.nodes
2
```